# How to get a list of comments and replies from a docs and add content to a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I would like to get a list of comment and reply from doc and add content of comment and reply in sheet (3 first comments and replies) structured as:

> Name of the file | date | update date | Url | Comment1 | reply1 | Comment2 | reply2 | Comment3 | reply3

The script I have now:

```
    function listfichier(){
     var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID_of_folder'); 
     var list = [];
     list.push(['Name', 'Date','update date', 'URL', Comment]);
     var files = folder.getFiles();
     
     while (files.hasNext()){
     file = files.next(); 
    var comments;
    comments = Drive.Comments.list(file.getId());
    Logger.log (comments.items.length);
    if (comments.items && comments.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < comments.items.length; i++) {
        var comment = comments.items[i];
      }
        var row = []
       row.push(file.getName(),file.getDateCreated(),file.getLastUpdated(),file.getUrl(), comment.content, comment.replies)
       list.push(row);
    } else {
      Logger.log('No comments found.');
    }

     }
      sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
    }
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Apart from closure as duplicate : could you please clarify what exactly is you want to do here? We understand that you want to create a list of comments, but is there a problem with your code?

Comment: sorry, i don't want to create comments.

I have pdf files on the google drives, users can create comments and replies on the files.
I want to read these comments, replies and save it on the sheet
in this script i can't read the replies content for files

Comment: if you need replies, you should look into [`Replies` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/replies), not comments. Btw, yeah, I get that you do not want to create comments, but you want to create a *list* of them and set to a sheet, right?

Comment: yes. i want to create a list  of both (comments and replies) and set to a sheet.
thanks

Comment: So... is there a problem, do you get an error, the script takes too long to run to completion, no replies are returned?

Comment: i need return just content and displayName Property of reply